# Do USB cables lose their rapid/fast charging over time?

Tags: usb, charging, mobile-phone

I have several new micro USB cables. I have a phone which can be charged quickly using a fast charger. The screen says' Charging Rapidly' when it's fast charging. After a few months, the rapid charging becomes just regular charging. The screen says Charging instead of Rapid Charging. I replace the cable and it's back to Rapid Charging.

The old cable is not bent or kinked. My question is.. do USB cables lose their ability to fast charge over time or is the issue with the cable connector? I will try to bring up the two springy things because they look like they are flat with the surface of the connector. Maybe it will make a difference.

Comment: Dust, oxides, etc. can affect - they increase power losses and reduce the current at the connection point.

Comment: Don't forget cables with more and more broken litz wires inside. This can effectively prevent fast charging.